# Mysql Error in fields list

Tags: php, mysql

This is my list of fields:

```
$fields = "ID, PropertyID, DateAdded, DateUpdated, RegionName, PropertyType, OtherType, SaleType, Condition, Price, CurrencyName, Title, MainImage, Summary, NoOfBeds, NoOfBaths, NoOfReceptionRooms, Floor, FloorSpace, Furnished, Pool, Garden, CoveredArea, MeasureUnit, Parking, DistanceSea, DistanceAirport, DistanceGolf, DetailNotes, FeaturedProperty, Sold, vrTour, Outbuildings";
```

And for some strange reason I am getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Condition, Price, CurrencyName, Title, MainImage, Summary, NoOfBeds, NoOfBaths, ' at line 1

Has anyone ever come accross a problem in the field names, I have ages ago but can't remember how I solved it, and hey, I didn't know about SO then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Condition
```

condition is the mysql reserved word use backquote to avoid error

```
`Condition`
```

Here is the list of mysql reserved words

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Condition is a reserved keyword in mysql.  If you really want to use it as a field name, you have to wrap it in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

"Condition" is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) and such needs to be used in backquotes.